# Loading content using AJAX but keep full page when visiting

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, delta

I have been trying and researching effortlessly for a quite few days now.

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is AJAX between pages. I know how to load content with AJAX/JQuery from a file into a page but it's a bit different.

Let's say there are 2 pages.

Index.php
Info.php

When I click a link from Index.php to Info.php, only the content in a certain DIV (like main content) needs to be replaced.

However, when I visit Index.php, I get the full page with headers and all that. (obviously)
But, if I visit Info.php, I also want to get that full page with headers and everything (just with the difference in the content DIV).

I see this on website quite a lot but just can't seem to find or figure out how it works.

It could also basically maybe be something like just replacing everything that's different between the two pages? (Like delta loading, as it seems to be called)

The main thing for all of this is to keep a music player playing fluently between page loads.

Can anyone explain how this would work or push me in the right direction?

Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

Assume that your all content of page in `#container` div

your navigation links looks like

```
<a href="index.php" class="ajax_link">Home<a>
<a href="infor.php" class="ajax_link">Information<a>
```

in your javascript code with jquery

```
function ajaxPageLoader(request_url) {
    console.log("Content loading from : "+request_url);
    $("#container").load(request_url+" #container", function() {
        window.history.pushState({}, "", request_url); // update current url in browser.
        console.log("Content loaded");
    });
}

function changeState(state) {
    if(state !== null) { // initial page
        ajaxPageLoader(state.url);
    }
}
```

This is delegated event handler using `on()` method

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.ajax_link',function(){
        ajaxPageLoader($(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
    });
});
// back button event
$(window).on("popstate", function(e) {
    changeState(e.originalEvent.state);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Oh, that works like a charm.. thanks!
Seems so simple though it would have taken me another week to figure that out.
When I use the back button, it seems to go back in the URL bar but the page stays the same. I don't understand this code fully enough yet to be able to fix it I guess. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to hear from you... If you like this solution...please dont forget to give up vote and mark as correct.. Always welcome..

Comment: I tried but it said this: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." :)